# can't start my first app on struts2

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, struts2

I'm new in java web apps. Do this example: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/struts_examples.htm

But can't start it in browser. Tomcat is properly working and shows me it's start page for `localhost:8080`. When I do

```
localhost:8080/HelloWorldStruts2/index.jsp
```

request as it shown in the example I see only :

```
HTTP Status 404 - /HelloWorldStruts2/index.jsp
type Status report
message /HelloWorldStruts2/index.jsp
description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/8.0.20
```

Please help to solve the problem.

Comment: You can't access a resource while it's not available. Try another resource if you can get a success status then simply move your file.

Answer (score 0):

Did it deploy the `HelloWorldStruts2` module properly?

I suggest you check Tomcat logs (located in **`tomcat home -> logs`**) to see if an exception happened while deploying the Struts app.

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer since it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Dave Newton, I'd love to comment instead, but it requires 50 reputation, so this it the best I could do :D